# How to spoof location to do testing with LocationClient and Geofences on Android?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I've been working with the `LocationClient` and have setup a `Geofence`, but don't know how to test it.

The issue comes from the fact that you can't run the app in an emulator, because `LocationClient` uses `GooglePlayServices` which are unavailable in an emulator. You also can't use `MockLocations` as far as I know, because you use `MockLocations` by creating a Provider, and `LocationClient` doesn't let you set a Provider.

So... how am I supposed to test my `Geofence`? (Besides getting in the car...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most phones have a debug setting to enable mocking the location.

For example on my Samsung S3 it's under

> Settings->Developer options->Allow mock locations

After turning this on you need an app from the play store that sets the location.

As an example
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works with LocationClient? It'll work with things using LocationManager, but I haven't had any success with those working with LocationClient. I've even disabled traditional providers (GPS & WiFi), and attempted to connect the LocationClient with only the spoofing app active, and that just caused the LocationClient to fail.

Comment: Nevermind, this totally works on a different test device. Either my other test device functions differently, or I just screwed it up :)

Comment: Update: It works, but very inconsistently. It looks like spoofers turn off all providers except 'network,' then fakes the network location. However, on ICS and JB (haven't tested earlier), it only works some of the time, and beets me as to why it picks up the fake one sometimes and the real one other times. I've even turned off GPS and only left on Network.

Comment: There was one note I saw to make sure the spoofer app is running before you start the app you want to taste as otherwise it doesn't pick up the fake location provider.